# Stop godog from parsing Scenario Outline example data table rows

Tags: go, bdd, gherkin

I am not sure it this is intended to be so, but I am confused by the behavior.

When I have the following Scenario Outline:

```
Scenario Outline: outline1
Given url
And query parameters <query_params>
When method
Then status is
Examples:
| method | endpoint   | query_params | status |
| GET    | /endpoint1 | ?a=1&b=1     | 200    |
| GET    | /endpoint1 | ?a=1&b=1&c=3 | 200    |
```

I see the following snippet generated.

```
func FeatureContext(s *godog.Suite) {
s.Step(^method GET$, methodGET)
s.Step(^query parameters \?a=(\d+)&b=(\d+)$, queryParametersAB)
s.Step(^query parameters \?a=(\d+)&b=(\d+)&c=(\d+)$, queryParametersABC)
}
```

As you can see 2 lines of "query parameters" produces 2 different functions. Why is godog parsing this text? This is a little different from cucumber gherkin parsing.

One side effect of this is that if I have 100 lines in the data table, I am forced to implement all of them.

Is there a way I can ask godog to not do this parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to use double quotes around  as given below.

```
Scenario Outline: outline1
Given url
And query parameters "<query_params>"
When method
Then status is
Examples:
| method | endpoint   | query_params | status |
| GET    | /endpoint1 | ?a=1&b=1     | 200    |
| GET    | /endpoint1 | ?a=1&b=1&c=3 | 200    |
```

Then the following will be generated:

```
s.Step(`^query parameters "([^"]*)"$`, queryParameters)
```